# How to get uploaded location of jar created by jenkins JOB

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am triggering jenkins build using jenkins-cli. Job gets started and jar gets created. I need to search the console output to get jar. Is there any way that I could retrieve location of jar created by jenkins build using any option?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the "Archive the artifacts" post-build action to your job and specify the relative path to your JAR in "Files to archive", e.g. `target/my-module.jar`.

Then your JAR of the last successful build will be available at the URL `http://jenkins.example.org/job/your-job/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/my-module.jar`. The job page in the web UI will list your JAR under "Last Successful Artifacts" and you can find more links to other builds like "Last stable build" under the "Permalinks" section.